# how do I get the tangent coordinates if I am given the quadratic function and the slope(gradient)

Tags: quadratics

I have the following task: calculate the coordinates of the intersections point between a straight line with a given slope and a quadratic function, so that you only receive one intersection instead of the normal two or none.
I am given the slope gradient m and the quadratic equation.
In this example its

```
y=x^2+3x-2   m=1
```

Comment: In order for there to be only one intersection, we need the line to be tangent. Do you have calculus at your disposal.

Comment: yes I do and I understand most of the quadratic formula material, but I hav etrouble with this one in particular, because I somehow have to force a result where both results of the quadratic formula are identical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the equation of straight line be $y = mx +c$.  Solve for the intersection: $$ mx+c = x^2 +3x -2$$
You get a quadratic in x.
$$ x^2 + (3-m) x -(2+c) = 0$$

To have only one intersection point, there should be only value of $x$ satisfying the above equation. So you make the discriminant of the above equation zero.

So now your x is simply $(m-3)/2$.

You know the value of $m$, so you know $x$, then you can find $y$ to know the intersection point

Comment: Since this isn't an equation, I'm not sure which part of is the discriminant

Comment: Sorry I forgot the Right Hand Side. That just came from the equation above it.

Comment: So just to make sure I got it, the basic jist of it is :
Step 1:set mx+b and ax^2+bx+c equal to each other                    
Step 2: Simplyfy the equation                                    
Step 3: Solve for x using the quadratic fomula                     
Step 4: Remove the discriminant                
Step 5: Solve remaing equation                   
Step 6: Put x in the parabola for y 
Thanks a lot btw

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

First, find the derivative of $y = x^2 + 3x - 2$.

$$y' = 2x + 3$$

Now set  $2x+3 = m = 1$.

Solve for $x$ to find the $x$ coordinate of the point you need.

Then place your solution for $x$ into the equation $y = x^2 + 3x -2$ to find the y-coordinate.

Comment: I don't really understand where you got y=2x+3 from and where why I should put the gradiant in a as the y coordinate, care to elaborate?

Comment: Have you learned about derivatives?  The only way a parabola and a line canintersect at exactly one point, is if $y'(1) = 1$.  That is, the line with slope $1$ must be tangent to the parabola when $y'=1 = 2x+3$.

Comment: No, I don't think so, but I think I sohuld be able to figure out how they work, I'm not sure if this they way my teacher intended me to solve this, but as long as they work, I fine with this solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t really need calculus to solve this problem thanks to a property of the parabola, namely, that a tangent to it doesn’t intersect the parabola at any other points. So, you are essentially looking for values of $b$ such that the line $y=x+b$ and the parabola $y=x^2+3x-2$ intersect in a single point. Setting the right-hand sides equal to each other and rearranging, you get the quadratic equation $$x^2+2x-(b+2)=0.$$ This equation has a single solution when its discriminant is zero, i.e., when $$4-4(b+2)=0.$$ I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: just a a question, isnt y=x+b missing the m? So it gives me y=mx+b or y=1x+b?, I know it doesn't acutaly matter this time, but just to make sure.

Comment: @user2741831 We’re given that $m=1$. [Swampnil’s answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2026156/265466) waits until later to make this substitution. If you want a solution to the general problem, then you need $ax^2+bx+c=mx+k$ to have a single solution for $x$, so you would have to solve $(b-m)^2-4a(c-k)=0$ for $k$.

Comment: Ok, think I got it now